# Black screen with movable mouse in Kubuntu 15.10 KDE - How do i fix it?

Tags: kubuntu, 14.10, kde

I accidentally moved my unstable power coord connected to my monitor (It gets disconnected easily) and couldnt get the power coord to fit in rightly, so i  had to force restart my computer  (cause i couldnt see anything to do a normal restart over the menus) to see if that was the problem, it turned out to not be the problem and i tried again getting the coord to work again, and succeeded. But now, after the force restart, i get a black screen, with a moveable mouse.(Note that i log in normally and there is a normal load screen) I can also open the window switcher by pressing alt+tab.
I am  able to open a virtual terminal (ALT+CTRL+f2,3,4 etc) but i dont know what to do from there.

TL;DR How do i fix the KDE desktop to be normal again? I think a force-shutdown broke it.

EDIT 1: Going into failsafe mode instantly returns me to the login screen

EDIT 2: in the black desktop, i can actually take screenshots and that will open a window.

EDIT 3: For a temporary workaround im going to install GNOME over TTY

Answer (score -1):

Seems like my session was corrupted, when logging in i chose the "Change session" function and restored to a previous one, everything works fine now.

Looks like i accidentally chose the "save session" option when shutting down? I have no idea.